# Scaling an mdframed box

Tags: mdframed, scaling, adjustbox

What is the trick for scaling an `mdframed` box?

If I comment out the `\begin{MyEnv}` and `\end{MyEnv}` in the `\adjustbox`, I get the scaling effect, but I want the entire `mdframed` box to be scaled?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{MyEnv}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[nobreak,userdefinedwidth=5cm]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}
Some text here.
\end{MyEnv}

\adjustbox{scale=0.75}{%
    \begin{MyEnv}
    Some text here.
    \end{MyEnv}%
}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's the wrong tool, I'm afraid: `mdframed` tries to split the framed box across pages, so it doesn't want to be in a horizontal box.

Comment: @egreg: Opps, forgot the `nobreak` option. Does that help?  Perhaps tcolorbox?

Comment: No, it doesn't help. `\scalebox{0.75}{\vbox{\begin{myEnv}...\end{myEnv}}}` seems to be the best one can get.

Comment: @egreg: Hmmm. That seems to work. Any reason to not use that solution with mdframed? `tcolorbox` seems to not require it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With paragraph content it is a good idea to wrap it in a `varwidth` first to box it properly:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{MyEnv}{%
    \begin{mdframed}[nobreak,userdefinedwidth=5cm]
}{%
    \end{mdframed}%
}%

\begin{document}
\begin{MyEnv}
Some text here.
\end{MyEnv}

\adjustbox{varwidth=\linewidth,scale=0.75}{%
    \begin{MyEnv}
    Some text here.
    \end{MyEnv}%
}%
\end{document}
```